# NSNotification and NSThread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nsthread, nsnotification

I create an object on a seperate thread using NSThread.

```
NSThread* myThread = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(createNewObject:) object:elements] autorelease];
[myThread start];  // Actually start the thread
```

That Object waits for an event. When that event occurs a notification is posted on the default notification center.

My AppController observes that notification and runs a selector.

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:MyNotification object:nil];
```

**Question:** Does the method (*myMethod:*) from the selector run on the main thread or on the thread from above (*myThread*) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thread in which you post the notification.

> In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the same thread in which an observer registered itself.  ([Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

**Footnote:** Objects can't wait for events.  Objects just exist.  Methods can wait for events.

Comment: Thx!!! (By saying "waits for event", I meant that it reacts on user interactions. Sorry for being unclear.)

Comment: BTW: Is there a way to figure out the name of the thread that runs a certain method?

Comment: @Daniel: Threads don't really have names.  Except for the main thread, that is.

Comment: I mean threads I created by myself, or the main thread. For example shouldn't be the name of NSThread *myGreatThread; be "myGreatThread" ?

Comment: If I write `int x = 3` that doesn't mean that the name of 3 is `x`.  Perhaps you should review an introductory programming textbook?

Comment: No, of course not ;) I was unclear again. Meanwhile I found out that you can set an name to a thread. With [NSThread currentThread] you can find out the current thread of execution. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/currentThread

Comment: You can also name pthreads using pthread_setname_np. On Lion or later, -[NSThread setName:] calls that, so the thread name will show up in samples, crash logs, etc...

Comment: Hm, it appears to be an extension.

Comment: @Daniel: In `NSThread *myGreatThread`, the thread is not named `myGreatThread`, the variable that may hold a pointer to a thread is named `myGreatThread`. You can name a thread, as you already found, but you must do that yourself, by sending a message to the thread object to set the thread object's name.